# Are there any studies on links between clothing style and personality?

Tags: personality, preferences

Reading about on personality psychology, I have met several vague claims that different personality types prefer different clothing styles.

- Apparently, people who are more keen to their senses will prefer softer clothes.
- People who highly value order and efficiency have been said to prefer a more formal clothing style.

Are there any research studies to support such claims? (I'm looking for links to scientific reports)

Comment: Similar question: http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/5497/what-personality-traits-does-sexy-and-revealing-clothing-correlate-with

Comment: I'm not thinking about sexy or revealing clothing, though.

Comment: Could you include references to those 'vague claims' you have read?